# Conditionally rendering an array within an array within the return statement?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've tried many of the methods outlined by other users, but no dice. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Essentially, I'm referencing idNumbers, an array of booleans (initialized to false), with each index corresponding to a different instance of a "file" object. I want to access this array and use the boolean held at each index to determine if the content in file should be rendered or not. My onClick() calls a function that toggles the boolean at whatever index is passed to it.

Right now, I'm displaying the button just fine, but the content will show regardless. Clicking the button doesn't do anything. I'm not using a simpler method because I don't know how many file objects there are, and so it has to be dynamic.

The return statement, which is inside of a Results component (which pulls from the Content component):

```
return(
   <div>
       {content.fileInfo.map(file => 
           <div>
               <button className="button" onClick = {toggleFile(file.id)}> 
                    {file.title} 
               </button>
               {content.idNumbers[file.id] && (<div>{file.content}</div>)}
           </div>
        )}
       {content.someOtherStuff}
   </div>
);
```

The bool array, returned from the content component:

```
const idNumbers = []; 
idNumbers.push(false); //sample. this was done in a .map, though.
```

My toggleFile function:

```
const toggleFile = (id) => {
      content.idNumbers[id] = !content.idNumbers[id];
};
```

I've been messing with this for hours. Please let me know what I can change so I can get this working. I'm aware this isn't an elegant solution either way, but I'm just trying to get the bare bones working. Thank you.

EDIT: figured I should clarify...{file.content} is itself an array.

EDIT2: the file object, which is made within a .map(file,index) and added to an array of files:

```
fileObj = { 
    title: {file.title},
    id: index, 
    content: [] 
};
```

Comment: No, file is actually an object (see edit) and the ids are simple 0, 1, 2, 3... since the file objects are in an array.
The greater program is kind of winding and confusing, so unfortunately I can't include it all here. But it works properly, and I know the indices are as expected.

Comment: What causes a component to re-render?

Comment: I didn't even know re-rendering was a thing (I'm very, very, very new at this). Thank you. Now, though, I'm unsure how on earth I'm going to have a variable number of states that will correspond to this format I've set up...Although, if it's not re-rendering, shouldn't that mean that none of the content is showing (because the array is initialized to all false)...? So it still seems like something's broken.

Comment: Can put make a sample on codesandbox?

Comment: I wish I could. I've altered the code in my question because I'm contracted to work on some features, but I'm not allowed to share code. So I don't think it would be possible, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger a re-render. This is done by calling `setState()` or `this.forceUpdate()` .

I can't tell where your contents is coming from (i.e. props, state, or somewhere else) but you should not be modifying it directly if its a prop. Instead, you should notify the parent component that something has happened via a callback (and let the parent component modify the data at its source). This is referred to as a controlled component. The other option is to handle it internally via state. This is an uncontrolled component. You see it a lot with form controls.

`setState` requires that state actually change. You can do this by increasing a counter or actually changing internal data. If you aren't storing data internally, I find `setState` + a counter to be annoying and instead just rely on `forceUpdate`

If you are using React Hooks, I believe you are forced to use `setState` and a counter. Except it would look something like

```
let [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

// Inside click method
setCounter(counter + 1);
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand. If I only have one of the collapsibles open at a time, then I could have a setState that reflects the id of the form info I want open. I'll look into this.forceUpdate() as well.